# How does the sum of a chain linked prices series for the chain linked year equal exactly the sum of the same year of the current prices series

Tags: mathematical-economics, gdp

[image]

Above are the current prices GDP and chained 2015 prices GDP for South Korea

The chained 2015 prices figures for each quarter don't match the current prices series for the period of 2015 (the chain linked year), but the sum for both series over 2015 equal 1054900.

Why doesn't the chained prices series match the current prices series for the year 2015 where it is chain linked to but the sum still matches? Is it a coincidence that the sums over the year are exactly the same?